# Can a spell check button be added to the Markdown editor?

Tags: feature-request, design, markdown

Every time before posting a question or an answer, I copy my write-up to MS word. I use the spelling checking function that corrects spelling mistakes and also corrects grammar.

Can such functionality be added directly to the markdown editor where we write our posts?

[image: markdown editor box]

Comment: Alternate solution: use a browser or browser add-on that automatically spellchecks text in text areas.

Answer (score 7):

It's not worth it

1. Most major PC browsers support spellcheck out of the box

[image: Explorer]

[image: Opera]

[image: Chrome]

[image: Firefox]

2. Mobile devices handle spell-check at the keyboard level

Adding an additional level of spellcheck would be superfluous at this stage.

Comment: Likewise, the dictionary that most modern browsers use are "good enough" but still fail to correct simple issues. And yet, the built-in spell checking software on a browser is still leagues better that most website plug-in. (With word processors having the best system altogether.)

Comment: Or rather, in the box...